# iptables to drop input connections to postgres

Tags: linux, postgresql, iptables

For testing, I need to drop all input connections to postgres db running on port 5432 on localhost. I set an iptables rule :

```
iptables -A INPUT -s 127.0.0.1 -p tcp --dport 5432 -j DROP
```

But I am able to do read/write operations to the db. I used dbvisualizer as well as the product to test. What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this is the right method but rule

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 5432 -j REJECT
```

worked as expected.

Answer (score 1):

The target DROP will just drop the packet, no further processing or forwarding.

try this:

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -j REDIRECT --to-ports 5432

Comment: it didn't work. It added rule `REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited` to iptables.

Comment: Hmm, I get "REDIRECT tcp  --  anywhere anywhere redir ports 5432" on my system. Can you try it on clean tables. Also check dmesg for errors.

Answer (score 0):

Did your server listen on localhost or ethernet nic network ip address?

Comment: I guess it's localhost. I connected to server through dbvisualizer using ip 127.0.0.1.